# Is it possible to delay a variable in a for-loop with set timeout?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is it possible to delay the variable `value` inside `window.setTimeout` and have the milliseconds value of the timeout be my `time` variable below?

```
var value = null;
var time = 5000;

for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){


  if(value === "a"){
    console.log("You made it!");
  } else {
      console.log("You didn't make it!");
    }

time = time - 100;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "_delay_ a variable"?

Comment: Like, if you want a variable to go 5 seconds without doing anything, and then it will become whatever its value is and trigger an if statement or something.

Comment: So you want ur program to sleep for some defined time and then work again ?

Comment: I think you mean `if(value == "a")`

Comment: I think in JavaScript it is ===

Comment: Both `==` and `===` comparisons would work, as long as it's not `=` which is assignment. The difference between `==` and `===` is that `===` is stricter in its comparison regarding the types it's comparing. Although it's also an extra character as well as a more recent addition to JavaScript that won't work in some older browsers. Both are equally valid and a matter of taste.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    setTimeout(function(){ 

    alert('hello');
    }, 5000);  

alert('hey');
}
```

But it'll work in different way. It'll give "hello" right away and after 5 seconds it'll show "hey" .

You can use "clearTimeout()" method to clear timeout .

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do That using setInterval() method:

```
var myVar=setInterval(function() {
    //codehere
        }, 100);
```

Here 100 millisecond is the Interval

Use `clearInterval()` to stop time:

```
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Here `myVar` is the variable name of setInterval function.

Comment: Could I make the 100 millisecond value my time variable?

Comment: Yes You can do that , use it in Your code.
reference link :
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Also, is there any way to stop it, or is it more like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback function to do so

```
 var value = null;
 var time = 5000;
 var limit=30;
 var i = 0; 
 function delay(limit, time, callback) {             
      loop();
      function loop(){
          if(value = "a")// it may be a comparison (you are assigning value).
          {
               setTimeout(function(){
                    i++;
                    if (i<=limit && time >= 0){
                        callback("callback after"+time);
                        callback("You made it!");
                        loop();
                    }
                }, time)
           }

           else
           {
                  callback("You didn't make it!");
           }

           time=time-100;
      }
 }


// Calling  a callback function
delay(limit,time, function(callback){
console.log(callback);
```